# Wordpress blog being hit by some bot

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy, bots

I am new to Wordpress .The problem I am facing is that someone using amazonaws server IPs is trying to spam or to do Dos on my site just hitting the index page after an interval of 2 seconds continuously  the user agent used for this is Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (FlipboardProxy/1.1; +http://flipboard.com/browserproxy) . i have blocked some ranges of Amazonaws severs but the hitting is still continuously going on at my site . What should i do to stop it? . Will be Thankful for your help

Comment: Personally I like using http://www.wordfence.com/ to identify bots and verify its validity.  This helps with other security issues as well.  It may slow down load time of the site but adding some type of security to your site is a way to help your situation.

Comment: you also could try cloudflare, and their plugin for wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to get bots no matter what you do. In most cases this is a good thing. In this case someone is using Flipboard (Mobile newsreader app) in conjunction with your site.

What you want to do is limit the impact that bots like this have on your site. You can do that by caching as much as you can so that the content comes from static caches as much as possible.

You can start with using Wordpress caching plugins (preferably with memcached or other memory caching options)

If that is not enough, configure your site with Varnish cache.

Answer (score 0):

1) Contact https://flipboard.com/browserproxy/ and tell them your site is getting hit too hard; they should be able to limit/kill the requests.

2) Use http://wordpress.org/plugins/block-bad-queries/ and other security plugins in the WP plugin directory.

3) And try http://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-login-attempts/ for general WP login security